# Is it possible to create a tile 2x2 mosaic using Sharp Node?

Tags: node.js, image, sharp

Using `Image Magick` I was able to use `montage` to make this:

[image]

With this code:

```
montage -density 300 -tile 2x0 -geometry 150x150^ -gravity center -crop 150x150+0+0 -border 0 '.$img_array.' /var/www/html/uploads/output.jpg
```

I would like to know if this is possible too using Sharp, I saw the `tile` option but I don't understand how to use 4 different images together.

Comment: where you able to have a solution for this? I want to achieve the same thing with Sharp as well.

Comment: @user2252310 yep, sorry I was a little busy...I will post an answer next days. If you are in a hurry you can find the solution in git repository under issues

Comment: @user2252310 please check the new answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the [Author](https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues/3138), I found this tricky solution.

Imagine you want a 2x2 mosaic with a fixed size of 400x400 pixels.

In the example below I have all my images into `./images/` folder. All 4 images are of fixed size 200x200 pixels.

You need also a background picture big enough to contain the mosaic. You can use for this any image and resize with Sharp as well.

```
const sharp = require('sharp');
 
sharp('./images/output4.jpg')
  .resize(400, 400)
  .toFile('bg.jpg', function(err) {
    console.log("Something wrong",err)
  });
```

Now that you have created the `bg.jpg` image you can run this JavaScript:

```
const sharp = require('sharp');
 
sharp('./images/bg.jpg') //here call the previous generated image
  .composite([
    { input: './images/output1.jpg', gravity: 'northwest' },
    { input: './images/output2.jpg', gravity: 'northeast' },
    { input: './images/output3.jpg', gravity: 'southwest' },
    { input: './images/output4.jpg', gravity: 'southeast' },
  ])
  .toFile('combined.jpg');
```

In the future will be easier with something like this (not yet implemented):

```
 vips arrayjoin "./images/1.jpg ./images/2.jpg ./images/3.jpg ./images/4.jpg" out.jpg --across 2
```